# Javascript filtering content on checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have code like this

```
<div id="filter">
</div>
<div id="items">
    <div class="item">
        <h2>Orange</h2>
        <img src="orange.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h2>Banana</h2>
        <img src="banana.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to filter divs with class "item" on its childs img src values. For example, If I checked input witch value banana.png only .item with same img src value should be displayed. Rest must be hidden.

And if you uncheck checkbox, control should be make again - items that were hided by checking that checkobox should be displayed again.

I have got same code that creates proper checkboxes, but how to make rest?

```
$("#items > div").find("img").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr("src");
    $("#filter").append('<label><input type="checkbox" [value="' + value + '"]>' + value + '</label>');
    var toFilter = $("#items > div").find("img");
});
```

You can see my codepen as well http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMpGaE?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the `div`'s like this using the `change` event of checkboxes.

```js
$("#items > div").find("img").each(function() {
  var value = $(this).attr("src");
  $("#filter").append('<label><input type="checkbox" value="' + value + '">' + value + '</label>');
  var toFilter = $("#items > div").find("img");
});
$('#filter').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
  var checkedArray = $('#filter :checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  if (checkedArray.length) {
    $("#items .item").hide();
    match = $("#items > div").find("img")
      .filter(function() {
        return checkedArray.indexOf($(this).attr('src')) != -1;
      }).closest('.item').show();
  } else {
    $("#items .item").show();
  }
})
```

```css
#items > div {
  border: 1px dotted #355B78;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter">

</div>
<div id="items">
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Orange</h2>
    <img src="orange.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Banana</h2>
    <img src="banana.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Orange</h2>
    <img src="orange.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>Banana</h2>
    <img src="banana.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good, But when you uncheck input, it hides everything.

Comment: @KarolinaTicha Updated.